# Installation of TYPO3 12.4. via composer is not working

Tags: composer-php, typo3

I installed TYPO3 12 via composer on apache with php 8.2.0 and mysql 8. During installation i get the error

```
In PathUtility.php line 167
[ParseError]
syntax error, unexpected ')'
```

The page mydomain.con/typo3/install.php stays blank, i get no php errors, i can not install TYPO3 12 via composer. Installation via zip works fine. How can i debug the problem?

Comment: Sure, you have on command line a php 8.2, too? line 167 is `$paths = array_map(GeneralUtility::fixWindowsFilePath(...), $paths);`. I assume it's the "..." - but that's part of PHP since v8.1: https://wiki.php.net/rfc/first_class_callable_syntax

Comment: I needed to run the php commands like /usr/iports/php82/bin/php ./vendor/bin/typo3 setup to make it work.